# How can I visualize the movement of an agent between a source and sink block in AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic

Similarly to this [model](https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/93cd1cb3-1f37-4c57-8f0a-cffaec8324d4?mode=SETTINGS), I would like to visualize the movement of an agent but between a source an a Sink block? Is this possible? I feel like the agents jumps between the boxe

Comment: uhm, why don't you download the model and investigate how they did it? Just click the "Model source files" link and open it in AnyLogic.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a queue and conveyor to visualize agents moving. In this simple example, make sure you specify the node the agents are sourced at and the path the agents are taking for both the queue block and conveyor block. You can also specify the speed at which they move along the path between the source and sink nodes.

[image]